# How to print multidimensional array foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [speaker_name] => John
    [events] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [event_id] => 1
                [event_name] => Event1
                [types] => Array (
                    [0] => Type1
                    [1] => Type2
                    )
                )
            [1] => Array (
                [event_id] => 2
                [event_name] => Event2
                [types] => Array (
                    [0] => Type1
                    )
                )
            [2] => Array (
                [event_id] => 3
                [event_name] => Event3
                [types] => Array (
                    [0] => Type2
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

How to print this like this,

John - Event1 - Type1, Event2 - Type2

..................................................................................
Thanks.

Comment: Have a read of the duplicate, it shows various types of JSON data and how to loop over the data to output it.  If you still have problems, ask a question with your attempts and where the problem is (along with any errors).

Comment: hi brother, i have updated my code

Comment: It just seems that you have replaced the original JSON string with a variable output.  There doesn't seem to be any code in the question.